# Fourier transform of Rect and sinc functions

Tags: integration, signal-processing, fourier-transform

How to transform rect function $\Pi(t/2)$ to $8 \text{sinc}(4t)$

Is there a way without using the inverse formula?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me say that your question was not clear. Eventhough, I will proceed computing the Fourier transform of $x(t) = \Pi (t/2)$, which is, I guess, what you are asking for. Note that $x(t)$ can be expressed as

$$
x(t) = \begin{cases}
1 \quad \text{if |x|<1} \\
0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.
$$
Let us take $x(t)$ and simply apply the general Fourier transform definition and see what happens. I will be using the ordinary frequency $f$.

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) ~e^{-j2 \pi f t} dt = \int_{-1}^{1}1 \cdot e^{-j2 \pi f t} dt = \int_{-1}^{1} ~e^{-j2 \pi f t} dt= \bigg[\frac{e^{-j2 \pi f t}}{-j2 \pi f}\bigg]_{-1}^1 = -\frac{1}{ j2 \pi f}\bigg[{e^{-j2 \pi f t}}\bigg]_{-1}^1 \\
&= \frac{1}{j2 \pi f} (e^{j2 \pi f}-e^{-j2 \pi f}), \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \text{(1)}
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

where $j = \sqrt{-1}$. By definition, we have that $\sin(x) = \frac{e^{jx}-e^{-jx}}{2j}$, and hence we can reformulate (1) as

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = \frac{\sin(2\pi f)}{\pi f} = \frac{2 \sin(2\pi f)}{2 \pi f}
\end{equation}

By definition, we know that $\text{sinc}(x) = \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}$, and hence we finally obtain that

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{F}\{x(t)\} = 2\text{sinc}(2f)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Fourier Transform is used for digital signal processing.
The standard form of F.T. is F(ω)=∫f(t)e^(-iωt) dt for -∞≤t≤∞. For example, find the F.T. of a rectangle function, rect(t), for rect(t)={1 if -1/2<t<1/2, 0 otherwise}: The product f(t)rect(t) can be understood as the signal turned on at t=-1/2 and turned off at t=1/2. So, F(ω)=∫(1)e^(-iωt) dt. Integrate the integral from -1/2 to 1/2 and the F.T. for f(t) is F(ω)=sinc(ω/2).
The sinc function is written as sinc(x) and has two forms: normalized and unnormalized. Digital signal processing usually uses the normalized form.

Comment: The Fourier Transform can be used in digital signal processing, but its uses go far beyond there. It can be used in differential equations, probability, and other fields. Although "standard" is up to the author, I consider the standard form to be $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x$ This normalization requires no constants for the inverse, which is given by $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat{f}(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}\,\mathrm{d}\xi$.

Comment: Consider using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It makes the posts easier to read.